# Disable checkbox conditionally XtratTreeList

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

How can I disable checkbox conditionally in my XtratTreeList ?
I have [NodeChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_NodeChangedtopic) and [CustomDrawNodeCheckBox](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_CustomDrawNodeCheckBoxtopic) events.

If I use `treeList1_CustomDrawNodeCell` event that gives me only ONE node.
i.e.

```
using DevExpress.XtraTreeList;
using DevExpress.Utils.Drawing;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo;
//...
void treeList1_CustomDrawNodeCell(object sender, CustomDrawNodeCellEventArgs e) {
    CheckEditViewInfo editViewInfo = e.EditViewInfo as CheckEditViewInfo;
    if (editViewInfo == null) 
        return;
    editViewInfo.CheckInfo.State = ObjectState.Disabled;
}
```

I have relations among nodes. If user check one node, only nodes related to that node should allow check/be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Devexpress does not have a direct way to do it, so, tou need to do the folowing :

To change their appearance accordingly, handle the `CustomDrawNodeCheckBox event`

```
private void treeList1_CustomDrawNodeCheckBox(object sender, CustomDrawNodeCheckBoxEventArgs e)
{
    //Your condition
    e.ObjectArgs.State = ObjectState.Disabled;
}
```

To prevent particular checkboxes from being checked, handle the `BeforeCheckNode event`

```
private void treeList1_BeforeCheckNode(object sender, CheckNodeEventArgs e)
{
    //Your condition
    e.CanCheck = false;
}
```

Hope this help ;)